# Solve the matrix with semi-orthogonal projection $A=V^\top X V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, orthogonal-matrices

$V \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a semi-orthogonal matrix, i.e., $V^\top V = I$, with $m > n$.
With the following equation:
$$A = V^\top X V $$
$A, V$ are given, how to get a closed-form solution of $X$ ?

Discuss:

- $V$ is not a square, so can't take the inverse.
- if extend $V$ to a square form $U$ (orthogonal matrix), and how to construct $U$ (make it invertible)

Comment: $X = VAV^T$ solves it, but it's not the only one

Comment: @Exodd, Thanks, this is one of the trivial solutions. Are there any other approaches? Since $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ has more entries than $A$. there must be multiple solutions that exist.

Comment: In general all solutions are in the form $VAV^T+Y$ where $V^TYV = 0$